# SAS instead of SATA 2 for my hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, sas

I am building a new system soon, I will have multiple 1-2tb hard drives for storage in it.  I only have experience uasing the sataII drives but I saw somewhere that I should be using something like SAS?  I read that if I were going to have 20 drives that I could use 4 SAS cables vs 20 SATA cables.

Can someone help me understand this better?  If it were only 4 cables then how would 20 drives hook up?  Also can a regualr sata2 drive hook up to that?